# How do I choose a default React Native debugging tool when I `Open the Dev Tools`

Tags: react-native, react-native-debugger, flipper

I am using both the [`Flipper`](https://fbflipper.com/) and [`React Native Debugger`](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger) on a React Native project.

I find JavaScript logging by `React Native Debugger` to be much richer given JSON formatting than Flipper (logs dumped as serialized strings). I however love the additional log tooling(especially for native logs) that Flipper provides.

> Is it possible to setup choose the default Dev tool?

Opening the dev tools on the iOS simulator, all logs open with `Flipper` even if it was quit and the React Native Debugger was already open.

[image: React Native Debugger Tools Screenshot - Awaiting Port 8081]

I have tried to configure a different port listened to by the debugger and dev tools but a flipper is still given the lead.

Has anyone tried to you both successfully?

Answer (score 1):

Not tried but seems like this article can help you out:

[Medium](https://medium.com/swlh/choosing-your-react-native-debugger-environment-dc1c4975775e)

Already given on [React-Native](https://archive.reactnative.dev/docs/debugging) official doc to setup default debugging tool.

If nothing messed up with your local setting then simple [disabling](https://fbflipper.com/docs/troubleshooting/#disable-flipper-on-ci-builds-ios) can help.

Comment: Thank you @sidverma. However, disabling Flipper is not an option right now. It offers so much value with native debugging. I visited the docs first but I mostly got out changing ports. Couldn't work.